# Does Chromecast come with a certificate bundle allowing simple webserver authentication/verification?

Tags: apache, ssl, ssl-certificate, chromecast

As I need to restrict webserver content to chromecast devices, I was hoping that chromecast devices have a certificate bundle, which can be used for authentication. The Chromecast documentation does not really state anything with regards to certificates.

So , my questions is does Chromecast come with a certificate bundle allowing the webserver to verify the client. iOS devices have sach a private/public certificate bundle, client verification/authentifcation using the public iOS certificate (.pem file).

The following snippet is part of a apache server configuration, I was hoping to extend this with Chromecast.

```
<Location /ios-hls-key>
  HLSEncryptHostCipherKey true
  HLSFmsDirPath ".."
  HLSEncryptKeyRepository "../media"
  SSLVerifyClient       require
  SSLRequireSSL
  SSLRequire %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN} eq "iPhoneOS Device Certificate"
</Location>
```

Anybody, knows or have any other ideas on how to limit webserver content to only chromecast devices?

Comment: Just wondering whether you had any links that says each iOS device comes with its own certificate and private key.

Comment: I must admit that these built-in client certificates (issued by Apple), that identify them as "official" Apple iPhones are not very well documented. Here one link explaining how to configure the Adobe Access Server (http://www.adobe.com/support/adobeaccess/pdfs/server/AdobeAccess_4_KeyServer.pdf). Here another pointing out issues with regards of certificate expiration (http://www.chasechristian.com/502/tech/ios-client-certificate-expiration-april-16-2014/). If you should stumble upon any offical documentation, please share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to the first part of the question is Yes. Chromecast uses a PKI to secure communication.
When Chromecast receiver app makes a secure http request (HTTPS/TLS), it is encrypted with a chromecast specific private key certificate (Which leads to Google). A server can use google's public key to decrypt the message and also extract information from the certificate if needed. This also means that you may not want to terminate the TLS on a load balancer and instead need the app server to do that. App server can store the google's public key and use it to decrypt it. There is a document which gives the details on how to decrypt and parse the certificate and what it has. I think if you have a developer account, you can get it.